# Find the function call behind a list

Tags: r

Suppose you have a list like the following:

```r
x <- list(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$cyl)
```

You just have access to `x`, you don't know what was the function call that created `x`. Is there a way to obtain the call that created `x`?

In other words, is it possible to pass `x` in a function and to obtain `list(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$cyl)`? (I'm trying to obtain `mtcars$mpg` and `mtcars$cyl`, it doesn't matter if they are in a list or not).

Comment: No, if you have a list without names, the history of its creation is not stored as part of the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a standard list without names, the history of its creation is not stored as part of the object.

All R objects represent an underlying C structure called an `SEXP`, which is a pointer to the data-storing object (the SEXPREC) along with a flag indicating the type of object. The SEXPREC of plain R lists, as in your example, are stored as three pointers (previous node, next node, and pointer to attributes such as names), followed by a block of pointers to the data objects stored in the list. The call that created the list is not stored anywhere within this structure. It is possible to create a list that has this information stored specifically as a data member or attribute, but it is not stored routinely in normal lists. See [here](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#SEXPTYPEs) for more information about the underlying data structure.

I'm very cautious about giving an answer that says something *can't* be done, and it *may* be possible in some circumstances to find which objects in the current session share memory with the list object, but I would assert that it is not possible in general.

If you want to create a list that contains the memory of how it was created, you could do something like this:

```r
list_mem <- function(...) {
  
  val <- list(...)
  attr(val, "call") <- match.call()
  val
}

x <- list_mem(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$cyl)

x
#> [[1]]
#>  [1] 21.0 21.0 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 17.8 16.4 17.3 15.2 10.4 10.4
#> [17] 14.7 32.4 30.4 33.9 21.5 15.5 15.2 13.3 19.2 27.3 26.0 30.4 15.8 19.7 15.0 21.4
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>  [1] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 6 8 8 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 4 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 8 6 8 4
#> 
#> attr(,"call")
#> list_mem(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$cyl)
```

But of course, this would have to be done specifically with this purpose in mind.